# Tailwindcss background-image not working in dark mode

Tags: css, tailwind-css, hugo

I have my Tailwind classes defined like this:

```
<section class="dark:bg-gray-900 bg-hero-image bg-fixed">
```

So in the light version a background image is shown and on the dark version just `gray-900` as background color.
The image is defined in `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero-image': "url('/header.jpg')"
      },
```

But this just doesn't work and still shows the image on dark mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `backgroundImage` to the `variants` in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: ["dark"],
    },
  },
```

**ALSO** you have to add `dark:bg-none` for the `background-image` to be set to `none`.

```
<section class="dark:bg-gray-900 dark:bg-none bg-hero-image bg-fixed">
```

This is also nessessary for things like `invert` and many other classes. Check the corresponding section in the docs, whether or not the variants are included by default.

> By default, only responsive variants are generated for invert utilities.
> https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/invert#variants

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='my-20 p-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-[#D1FFD0] to-[#BBE7FF] dark:from-[#263238] dark:to-[#263238]  dark:text-white rounded-[20px]'>
      <div>
        <p className='text-center text-[16px] md:text-[20px] font-semibold'>
          If you're still unsure about whether software development is the right
          fit for you, it may be comforting to know that the employment rate for
          software engineers stands at an impressive 93%*.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className='my-5'>
        <p className='text-center text-[16px] md:text-[18px] font-normal'>
          "Secure your spot now by reserving a seat and begin your journey as a
          software developer!"
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className='mt-6 flex items-center justify-center'>
        <button className='px-8 py-4 bg-[#00A3FF] rounded-[30px] text-white hover:transition hover:duration-5000 hover:ease-in-out hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-blue-400 hover:to-purple-500'>
          BOOK A FREE DEMO
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is for a normal gradient in light mode: `bg-gradient-to-r from-[#D1FFD0] to-[#BBE7FF]`

And `dark:from-[#263238] dark:to-[#263238]  dark:text-white` for dark mode.

Example:
[Dark Mode](https://prnt.sc/ZqmT9U-YMqAd)
Example: [Light Mode](https://prnt.sc/GhUMJHKM2WaA)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).